# break out of switch case

Tags: switch-statement, break

Wondering if I can break out of my case if the break is in an if statement, or if the break will just exit the if and not the case. I only want to fallthrough to the next case if the else is executed. Thanks

```
  case PS_STARTED:
     readyForPwrDn_b = appReadyForPwrDn_b;

     if (!readyForPwrDn_b)
     {
        break;
     }
     else
     {
        CurrentPowerState_e = PS_COMPLETE;
     }
     //fallthrough

  case PS_COMPLETE:
```

Comment: What programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as breaking out of an `if`. `break` applies only to `switch` and to loops in all the programming languages I'm familiar with.

[PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php):

> *break* ends execution of the current *for*, *foreach*, *while*, *do-while* or *switch* structure.

[Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break):

> The **break statement** terminates the current loop, switch, or label statement and transfers program control to the statement following the terminated statement.

[C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37zc9d2w.aspx):

> The **break** statement is used with the conditional switch statement and with the **do**, **for**, and **while** loop statements.

However, these all apply to non-labeled `break` statements. In some languages you can write:

```
myIf: 
    if (!readyForPwrDn_b) {
        break myIf;
    } else {
        CurrentPowerState_e = PS_COMPLETE;
    }
```

This would just break out of the `if`.

Comment: I know you can test an if statement to break a loop with `break` but I do believe you are correct here. I think he'd use continue or return would he not?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can `break` out of labeled block statements (Java specific, not sure about other languages)

Comment: @WhyCry `continue` can only be used in loops. It will go to the top of the loop, not just exit the `switch`.

Comment: @VinceEmigh All the examples I can find of labeled `break` statements have the label identifying a loop, it's typically used for exiting an outer loop from a nested loop. Can it be used to exit from a non-looping statement as well?

Comment: @Barmar

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7805b4b9-f778-4f04-a58a-b889d1395cf7/nested-if-statement-use-break-to-break-out-of-if-statment-only?forum=vcgeneral

I was reading here and this is why I got the goto idea.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. You can break without a loop by using a specified label. `label: { break label; }`

Comment: OK, I've added an example of that to my question. But obviously it doesn't apply in the OP's case -- you have to explicitly label the `if` and `break`, which you wouldn't do if you wanted to break out of the `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (condition)
{
    //Do your thing

    if (breakOutCondition)
        return;

    //Continue your code
}
```

This if statement would work, but there is an easy, clean way of getting out of a loop like this. You could use a `goto` to break this variable scope and it will make it loop a hell of alot cleaner. WARNING: `goto` is sometimes dreaded because it is essentially a break in disguise.

```
if (breakoutcondition)
{
    ...
    goto foo;
    ...
}
foo:
//Continue here
```

Comment: There's no reason to resort to a `goto` if `break` will do what you want.

Comment: Break will break out of the entire switch structure though. His question is kind of poorly explained in what he's looking for. Is he looking to continue through to the else, or completely break the switch?

Comment: He still hasn't given the language. If it's Javascript, `goto` won't work, since it doesn't have that statement.

Comment: Wow I read that incorrectly. Probably too quickly. That will just break the case as he wanted.